# Cannot use boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

When trying to use boost regex library by #include'ing boost/regex.hpp and then creating object of this class:

```
boost::regex empty_line("^\\s*$");
```

I'm getting following error while trying to compile it:

```
D:\...\boost\regex\v4\cpp_regex_traits.hpp:366: error: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you including the required lib when you compile the project?  Your compiler needs a link.

Comment: If you don't want to have to link to anything, use [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost regex is one of the few parts of boost that require you to build the boost library and link against it.

See: [Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#install-visual-studio-binaries) [Unix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install)